# Creating A Relationship With AspNetUsers Table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using database first. I have an Adopters table and a Owners table. I want both of them to have a relationship with the AspNetUser table. The end goal is to give users the choice to sign up as an Adopter or a Owner.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error I get when I try to register a user.]

Comment: Please provide information about your error.

Comment: So right now I decided on having it to where users can register. And from there, I will have them sign up as a Adopter or Owner. But, when I try to register a new user, i get the error: EntityType 'AspNetUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Comment: I have a AspNetUsers Foreign Key on my Adopter's and Owner's table. I'm not sure if that is the problem. @habib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for One to many relationship with AspNetUsers table
Use following code:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class Adopter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Question, how would I go about updating the db after adding these fk to the partial class?

Comment: Step 1.check migration folder is present in your folder or not.
Step 2. If not then open Nuget Package Console and type Enable-Migrations
Step 3. Above command will enable migration and you will be able to see migration folder.
Step 4. Write another command to add migration - Add-Migration
Step 5. Final command to update DB - Update-Database
After this your db should updated to new schema.

Comment: Try this git repo https://github.com/nitinsingh9x/AspIdentity if you need code.

Comment: When I try to enable migration for models.applicationdbcontext, i still get this error: EntityType 'AspNetUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Comment: It says I have two different context types when I just use Add-Migration. Is this because I have two different connection strings in my web config? Thank you for the repo.

Comment: Share your code some where or in github, will get back after having look on it.

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted. After redoing my database with the one to many relationship and changing my connection string, my code now works. I appreciate your help.